# Minimizing the difference between 2 numbers

Tags: optimization

Formulate as a linear optimization problem.
For given numbers a and b ﬁnd two numbers x and y whose difference is at most 1, such that |x −a|+|y −b| is minimal.

So far I know that |x −y| $\le$ 1 but I am not sure where to go next.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\mbox{Minimize }\; Z=\omega_1+\omega_2
$$
subject to
$$
x-y\le 1\\
-x+y \le 1 \\
x-a\le \omega_1 \\
-x+a \le \omega_1\\
y-b\le \omega_2 \\
-y+b \le \omega_2\\
$$